# Use Minimum Bounding geometry to define map extent in data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, extents

I am using Arc Map 10.4 and I have a layer containing municipalities. I need to print all of these municipalities on a separate sheet. I figured I could use data driven pages to accomplish this. However there are huge size and shape differences between the municipality polygons. I created a minimum bounding geometry for all the different municipalities. (Using geometry type = envelope)
Now I want to use data driven pages (or any other way) to print these municipalities so that the extent of each sheet is defined by the minimum bounding geometry. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the "minimum bounding geometry" another polygon layer?

Comment: If your municipalities is a polygon layer you could just use that as your reference layer.  Set the scale to a percentage of the feature (maybe 105% to give a bit of space around it) and it will set the extent of each page to the extent of the features.

Comment: @Midavalo - This should be an answer. Maybe add something about using the rotation field in the DDP index layer, too. Just in case some of the municipalities need to be portrayed in landscape vs. in portrait.

Comment: @cl3 if you can write something up with a bit more detail, go ahead - unfortunately I'm heading out the door for the day and don't have time . If not I'll write up at the end of the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your municipalities is a polygon layer you could just use that as your reference layer.

Set the scale to a percentage of the feature (maybe 105% to give a bit of space around it) and it will set the extent of each page to the extent of the features.